# ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED not send by Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

In my application I want to check if the phone is charged by socket or usb. For this I created a `BroadcastReceiver` with the following code:

**Manifest:**

```
<receiver
    android:name=".ChargingReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**ChargingReceiver**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);

    boolean acCharge = (chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC);
    boolean usbCharge = (chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB);

    //...
}
```

My problem is, that the first line of the `ChargingReceiver` always return `-1` which is the default value I have set. The BroadcastReceiver is called correctly when I plug or unplug my phone, so it looks to me that the intent does not contain the `Extra` I try to look up. I have the code from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) so it should work.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29789722/2047987) answer but it does not help me, because I have to distinguish between USB Charging and socket charging. Any ideas what I have done wrong? BTW I have tested the code with Android Nougat. I think on Lollipop it has worked, but I'm not completely sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You registered `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` in your manifest. But these Broadcasts don't include information about the charging state.

In order to receive information about the charging state you need to register the `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` broadcast. From the developer docs:

> The BatteryManager broadcasts all battery and charging details in a
>   sticky Intent that includes the charging status.

So you can try the following code snippet in `onReceive`:

```
Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
boolean pluggedAC = (plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC);
boolean pluggedUSB = (plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB);
```

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html)

Comment: Wow this works thank you for this! I think it is not the best solution because I react with a `Broadcast`to a `Broadcast` but since I can't register this `Intent` through the manifest it is the only solution so far I can use or do you have any ideas to beautify this? Or am I a bit to petty with this?

Comment: I think doing this in your Broadcast receiver would be a good solution since you only want to receive the battery status information in case the power connection state changed

Answer (score 1):

@MarkB approach is correct, it's the same one suggested in the developer docs. I would like to point out that you don't need to register any `BroadcastReceiver` because that's a **[Sticky Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038839/knowing-about-sticky-intent-in-android)**.

Basically all you need to do is to call `registerReceiver` passing in null as the receiver and of course the action (`Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`):

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

And then you can do it like this:

```
// Are we charging / charged?

int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                     status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

// How are we charging?
int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
```

*(These snippets are **not mine**, but from **docs**)*

Notice that there's nothing wrong doing this as also the docs suggests it.

Now, getting back to **your code** you are actually listeting for `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`, which are used to monitor changes in charging state and could be useful to handle the amount of battery you can use.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                            status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
```

As suggest by @MarkB you must explicitly register ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED from your Java code [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277524/1790537)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm sorry. This also does not work

Comment: what value you get for boolean isCharging?

Comment: It also return always `false`.

Comment: could you tell me your status value

Comment: It is also always `-1`. I found this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11602922/2047987) so I think it's okay that it returns always `-1`. I only register the BroadcastReceiver throught the manifest. But `EXTRA_PLUGGED` should work...